# How to disable the ViewModelViewHost transition

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I am using a `ViewModelViewHost` in my ReactiveUI WPF application to display a view for an arbitrary viewmodel. When changing the viewmodel, the control fades in/out the view as a transition. I would like to disable this animation. I have found a Transition property but it seems this can only be used to change the transition, not disable it.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the [default template for the TransitioningContentControl](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/dea8a4b2bc4fedaeecdc59328c1fa27d9e90c069/src/ReactiveUI.Wpf/Themes/Generic.xaml) by for example setting the `Duration` properties of all animations to 0:

```
<rx:RoutedViewHost
            Router="{Binding Router, Mode=OneTime}"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <rx:RoutedViewHost.Style>
        <Style TargetType="rx:TransitioningContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="rx:TransitioningContentControl">
                        <Grid 
                        x:Name="PART_Container"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PresentationStates">

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_PreviousContentPresentationSite" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="FadeTransition_OutIn">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_PreviousContentPresentationSite"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                            From="1" To="0"/>

                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_CurrentContentPresentationSite"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                            From="0" To="1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="FadeDownTransition_OutIn">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_CurrentContentPresentationSite" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                            From="-30" To="0"/>

                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_PreviousContentPresentationSite" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                            From="0" To="30"/>

                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_CurrentContentPresentationSite"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                            From="0" To="1"/>

                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_PreviousContentPresentationSite"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                            From="1" To="0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <!-- SlideLeftTransition -->
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SlideLeftTransition_In">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_CurrentContentPresentationSite"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-90"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-90"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0">
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                        <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_CurrentContentPresentationSite" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_PreviousContentPresentationSite" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="SlideLeftTransition_Out">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_PreviousContentPresentationSite" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                            From="0" To="-90"/>

                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_CurrentContentPresentationSite" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <ContentPresenter 
                            x:Name="PART_PreviousContentPresentationSite"
                            Content="{x:Null}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>

                            <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="PART_CurrentContentPresentationSite"
                            Content="{x:Null}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </rx:RoutedViewHost.Style>
</rx:RoutedViewHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying @mm8's answer, the `TransitioningContentControl` base class has a `Duration` property that can be set to zero.

```
<rx:ViewModelViewHost Duration="0">
...
```